How to get the value of selected text in select combobox by javascript in asp.net c#
How to get the value from selected text by select combobox?
Here is the aspx.cs code for bind combobox
service.BindHTMLDropdownList(cmb_labelno, "tbl_StockRunning", "StockTagNo", "StockId", "where IsActive = 1 and StockTypePrefix = 'T' and " +
    "BranchId = " + Session["BranchId"] + "");

Combobox Name : cmb_labelno
Table Name : tbl_StockRunning
Text : StockTagNo
Value : StockId
Here is the aspx code
<select id="cmb_labelno" runat="server"></select>
<input type="button" id="btnGetStock" value="VIEW"/>


$("#btnGetStock").click(function (e) {               
    alert(document.getElementById('cmb_labelno').value);
});

Now, the place of alert(document.getElementById('cmb_labelno').value I used
alert(document.getElementById('cmb_labelno').val also still value is not showing.
While the same thing if I am doing in Jquery still showing the selectedtext only not value
Here is my Jquery code,
document.getElementById('<%= cmb_labelno.ClientID %>').value

Is there any problem in code...???

You should do the following for getting the value from your select element.
I am going to attach a snippet.
First of all, I declare two variables called selectedValue and selectedText in a global scope so that I can afterwards log their values on the listener of the input type button whenever I click VIEW.
To get the selected option, you have to open label.options and then as if you would access an array, you insert the property selectedIndex as the index of your "array"(which is not array).
It is more like the Nodelist of your DOM element which contains the options with their corresponding value/text.
I am speaking in terms of arrays so that is more undestandable what I want to address here.


   // I have used pure vanilla javascript for getting the values for the select element
var label = document.getElementById("cmb_labelno");
let selectedValue = '';
let selectedText = '';


label.addEventListener("change", function(e){
 
  selectedValue = label.options[label.selectedIndex].value;
  selectedText = label.options[label.selectedIndex].text;
  console.log(selectedValue);
  console.log(selectedText);
});



$("#btnGetStock").click(function (e) {  
  console.log(selectedValue);
    console.log(selectedText);
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="cmb_labelno">
  <option value="1">test1</option>
  <option value="2">test2</option>
  <option value="3">test3</option>
</select>

<input type="button" id="btnGetStock" value="VIEW"/>



Hope that can help you with your problem.
